# How can an object move in the forward direction with the ability to turn?

Tags: c++, math, physics, game-physics

I have been attempting to move an object that I have control over in the forward direction, which I can do just fine, but as soon as I would like to implement having the ability to turn it seems as if any attempt I make can't seem to make the object turn properly. What always ends up happening is it starts to turn, then kind of just turns in on its self and goes into an unpredictable direction. What I would like to do so if I pressed my forward key, and held my right turn key at the same time, it would move in a circle.

What I have tried is the following

Moving Forward (works fine, when I don't do any sort of a turn). _13, _23 and _33 is my forward vector for my matrix.

```
float x = transform->getLocalTransform()._13 * (fowardmovement * elapsedtime);
float y = transform->getLocalTransform()._23 * (fowardmovement * elapsedtime);
float z = transform->getLocalTransform()._33 * (fowardmovement * elapsedtime);

// apply the movement as an impulse to the rigid body for the object
objectrigidbody->addImpulseForce(x, y, z);
```

I do the same thing for going backwards, but with a backwardmovement variable.

What I have tried to do for turning is just applying a rotation directly on the Y for the object.

```
// the function rotate applies the rotation directly to the object, with no return value
objectrigidbody->rotate(0.0, turnmovement * elapsedtime, 0.0);
```

Would anyone happen to know how I can get my object to be able to as if it was moving in a circle if I were to hold my forward and right turn key?

Comment: @Yakk: Any object in general

Comment: This is not a very good question.  No particular libraries are referenced so the functions don't have much meaning beyond variable and function names.  I.e. What does the member `_13` represent?  I dunno and guessing as to what is meant is a waste of time.  Please consider clarifying your question.  I think that is also what @Yakk was subtly trying to elude to.

Comment: @Adrian: The reason I did not overly explain things is because _13, _23 and _33 are very commonly known as the forward vector. Was there anything else that was unclear to you?

Comment: Well, without context, it makes for a difficult if not impossible to answer question.  A question should be able to stand on its own.  What is common to a one group is esoteric to the rest of the greater community.  I'd suggest adding more detail to improve the chances of a useful response from the group you are trying to reach.

Comment: Also I'd suggest you change your title.  That isn't even a question.  I'm not trying to be hard on you.  I'm trying to help you get a useful answer in a timely manner.

Comment: This is better, but still no context in regards to what library you are using.  You might want to put it in your title.  I.e. `How do I move an object forward using <lib name> and allow it to turn?`  (I'm only guessing if this is what you are asking).  When you say `it kind of just turns in on itself`, do you mean that the object turns around but still keeps going along the same path as before?

Comment: The reason I don't use <lib name> is because it is a general question, I am not using any library that is readily available. This is code that I have been writing (including my own matrix library and physics).

Comment: Fair enough.  And your answer to my question re When you say `it kind of just turns in on itself`?

Comment: By rocket, car or jet, I was asking "what do you mean by turning".  Turning a car is different than turning a jet which is different than turning a rocket.  (Admittedly, the car and jet are similar).  Even at a really rough level of approximation, rockets (which can face whatever way, and then trust) behave differently than things swimming through a medium (a car, swimming on the ground, or a jet, swimming through air), where direction of travel and direction you are pointing is identical or highly related.

Comment: How much is `turnmovement` usually? Maybe you have `turnmovement` set too high.

Comment: I have tried high values and low values, neither produced the value I was looking for.

Comment: Must be something wrong in the rotate() function then.

Comment: So you are saying that everything else seems to be correct?

Comment: It looks correct, I don't know what is going on inside those functions though.

Comment: You could point to a paste bin or other resource to give these guys a better idea of what's going on here. You have to give them a chance, lol.

Comment: As many people have already told you, you need to provide some more code if you want help, preferably an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're working with matrices of the form

```
[ side_x up_x forward_x position_x ]
[ side_y up_y forward_y position_y ]
[ side_z up_z forward_z position_z ]
[      0    0         0          1 ]
```

So to rotate around the local up vector `a` radians, multiply the local transformation matrix by a rotation matrix that rotates around the Y-vector, i.e.

```
[ side_x up_x forward_x position_x ]     [ cos(a) 0 -sin(a) 0 ]
[ side_y up_y forward_y position_y ] *=  [      0 1       0 0 ]
[ side_z up_z forward_z position_z ]     [ sin(a) 0  cos(a) 0 ]
[      0    0         0          1 ]     [      0 0       0 1 ]
```

Let me know how that turns out.

## BIG EDIT

Here's some more information.

#### Definition (Frame)

A *frame* F is a collection of four homogeneous coordinates x_F, y_F, z_F, o_F such that the fourth coordinates of x_F, y_F, z_F are zero and the fourth coordinate of o_F is one, and x_F, y_F, z_F are pairwise orthogonal (orthogonality is not *really* necessary, but I just define it like this here). o_F is called the origin of the frame. A collection of vertices is said to be *relative to frame F* if their coordinates are expressed with respect to F.

#### Example 1

A mesh made in Blender or Maya has its vertices expressed relative to the model's frame.

#### Definition (Frame transformation matrix)

Given two frames F and G, a *frame transformation matrix* M is a 4x4 matrix M such that

1. M * x_F = x_G
2. M * y_F = y_G
3. M * z_F = z_G
4. M * o_F = o_G

Written differently, we can express this as M * [x_F, y_F, z_F, o_F] = [x_G, y_G, z_G, o_G], where [ ... ] means the matrix spanned by the columns respectively. Again written differently, and assuming invertibility is of no concern, we may write

```
M = [x_G y_G z_G o_G] * [x_F y_F z_F o_F]^{-1}
```

#### Example 2

Suppose we need to transform from world space to view (or eye) space. We assume that world space coordinates are just the standard basis vectors, and we assume that our camera in view space is centered at o_V with some rotation applied to it such that we get the vectors x_V, y_V and z_V. Then M is simply equal to

```
M = [x_V y_V z_V o_V] * I^{-1} = [x_V y_V z_V o_V]
```

#### Example 3

Suppose now that we have a batch over vertices from a model and the vertices' coordinates are expressed in model space. The model is located somewhere in world space with some orientation. The model thus has an origin o_M and some rotation x_M, y_m, z_M. The matrix that transforms the vertices from model space to world space is then equal to

```
M = I * [x_M y_M z_M o_M]^{-1} = [x_M y_M z_M o_M]^{-1}
```

Observe that one must be aware that the matrix must be inverted.

#### Example 4

Suppose now that we want to go directly from model space to view space. This is now easy, since we already deduced the matrices for model -> world and world -> view. Hence

```
M = [x_V y_V z_V o_V] * [x_M y_M z_M o_M]^{-1}
```

#### Who cares?

A frame is a useful tool to implement the effects that you want. Suppose the objects in our world all have a `position`, a `forward` and an `up` vector. Our camera through which we look at is also an object in the world. Hence it also has a `position`, a `forward` and an `up` vector. A first version of a `Frame` class could be

```c
struct Frame { // version 1
    vec3 position;
    vec3 forward;
    vec3 up;
};
```

However we'd like to make our `Frame` do useful things. So we could add member functions.

```c
struct Frame { // version 2
    vec3 position;
    vec3 forward;
    vec3 up;
    mat4 getLocalToWorldTransform() const;
    mat4 getWorldToLocalTransform() const;
}
```

The `mat4 Frame::getWorldToLocalTransform() const` member functions could look something like this:

```c
mat4 Frame::getWorldToLocalTransform() const {
    vec3 side = crossProduct(forward, up);
    //          [x_F  y_F    z_F       o_F  ] (!!)
    return mat4(side, up, -forward, position); // +forward or -forward depending on the graphics API
}
```

If you notice though there could be a problem. Who guarantees that `up` and `forward` are always orthogonal? You'll have to take care of that yourself. For example, you could force yourself to only rotate the `forward` direction around the `up` vector so that they always remain orthogonal.
I'll leave the implementation details of `mat4 Frame::getLocalToWorldTransform() const` to you.

Now we'd like our `Frame` to be able to move about in the world. We could add more member functions

```c
struct Frame { // version 3
    vec3 position;
    vec3 forward;
    vec3 up;
    mat4 getLocalToWorldTransform() const;
    mat4 getWorldToLocalTransform() const;
    void moveForward(const float steps);
    void moveBackward(const float steps);
    void rotateClockwiseAroundUp(const float radians);
    void rotateCounterClockwiseAroundUp(const float radians);
}
```

The implementation of `void Frame::rotateCounterClockwiseAroundUp(const float radians)` could look something like this:

```c
void Frame::rotateCounterClockwiseAroundUp(const float radians) {
    direction = mat3::rotationFromAngleAndAxis(radians, up) * direction;
}
```

So, your camera should maintain its own `Frame` class. To rotate the camera, use the member functions `rotateCounterClockwiseAroundUp` and `rotateClockwiseAroundUp`. To move the camera backwards and forwards, use the member functions `moveForward` and `moveBackward`. To get the transformation matrix, use the member function `getWorldToLocalTransform`, because we need to go from world -> view space.

Comment: My matrix is row major, not column major. So you are saying that I should first apply the translation movement to the main matrix (changing position_*), then create a rotation matrix that has how much I have rotated, then multiple my main matrix by that temporary rotation matrix?

Comment: @chadb If you do it in that order, M_translation * M_rotation, then multiply your vertices as v' = M_translation * M_rotation * v then yes it should give you the desired effect. But I'll make an edit to my post hold on

Comment: Thank you for the help, what you provided was what I was able to use to lead me to a solution to the problem I have had for a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

As other comments have mentioned, you are moving in world space by just poking movement values into your matrix. This means you'd have to do the work of modifying the movement values to make them respect the the local orientation of the object. You want something that works like this (method names are made up, since as everyone has noted I don't know what your api is)

```
// apply the rotation.
// I'm assuming this is in local space, if there were a 'rotateLocal' function you should
// use that
objectrigidbody->rotate(0.0, turnmovement * elapsedtime, 0.0); 

// with made-up but probably available function
Vec3 forward = objectrigidbody.getForwardVector();
// most api's give you a method or property to get the worldspace vector that
// corresponds to 'forward' in your coordinate system.  Use that.


// scale that vector (I'm assuming it's a unit vector: they usually are)
// by speed:
forward *= fowardmovement * elapsedtime;

// apply the impulse:
objectrigidbody->addImpulseForce(forward.x, forward.y, forward.z);
```

Note even here I'm not sure you're getting what you want: does addImpulseForce add a one-time acceleration or is it setting a constant force.  I'd expect you want a constant force here unless you're doing asteroids-style navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Your rotation must be a function of amount of forward movement. Try rotating by forward movement divide radius of desired circle.

Comment: Could you pleas provide an example? I am unsure of how I should be rotating based upon your answer. Am I suppose to Rotate on X, Y and Z? It would seem to me that I would only need to rotation on the Y.

Answer (score 0):

The question is still unclear, but I'll take a stab at it.

It sounds like your forward and backward are working but the rotation is only causing the object to rotate while still moving along the axis that you are currently moving forward and backward on.

The reason is that there appears to be no discernible link between your forward direction and your rotation.  Put another way, the acceleration vector of the object doesn't take into account that the impulse vector is rotating.

Since your variable `transform` appears to be a pointer to some matrix with `->getLocalTranform()` applying some transformation matrix and `._x3` being a way to tease out some acceleration vector, I would appear to me that you are not applying the rotation matrix on the acceleration matrix.

Assuming that `objectrigidbody` is yet another matrix (this is unclear as the name does not describe that), perhaps you can do something like this:

```
float x = transform->rotate(0.0, turnmovement * elapsedtime, 0.0)
                   ->getLocalTransform()._13 * (fowardmovement * elapsedtime);
float y = transform->rotate(0.0, turnmovement * elapsedtime, 0.0)
                   ->getLocalTransform()._23 * (fowardmovement * elapsedtime);
float z = transform->rotate(0.0, turnmovement * elapsedtime, 0.0)
                   ->getLocalTransform()._33 * (fowardmovement * elapsedtime);
objectrigidbody->addImpulseForce(x, y, z); // to apply the movement
```

Which also assumes that rotate() returns a matrix.

---

Do you see what I am getting at when I say ***there is not enough information to answer your question???***  I have to assume way too much because there is **NOT** enough context.

If this is not what you are looking for, please add more context to the question or you will find you will not get any answer any clearer than this.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: You are right, my forward and backwards movement are not taking account of my rotation, which seems like a logical reason as to why I am having a problem. _13, _23, _33 is my forward vector of the matrix, not my acceleration vector. objectrigidbody is not another matrix, it is just the rigid body. transform->rotate does not return a matrix, it applies the direction to the matrix. Is there anything else that was unclear?

Comment: No, not unclear, just not available.  There is not enough information to answer this question.  Since this is not a standard library, you would need to provide the interface for all the classes that need to be used (for example including but not necessarily limited to your matrix class) and code context.  What you are asking is basically "I want to build X. Here is a subset of the code I wrote to do X which is out of context so has no real meaning to anyone but me.  Now help me."  Can you understand why this is a problem?

Comment: Not so much actually, the functionality I am talking about (basic rotation and matrix functionality) standard intro game development knowledge. That is why I don't explain what a rotate function is, or what a transform is. To say that is has no context would be wrong, that is the exact context. I also modeled my question in the same format that many other game development questions have been asked.

Comment: @chadb, say what you want as that is up to you.  I'm just telling you what I think.  I could give you a general idea what you can do and I have, and for that you haven't even upvoted showing any appreciation. I know what a transform is, that is something one learns even in high school.  But without code to show what you have done (I'm not here to code this for you), and an interface to code to (esp a non-standard one), all that I can say for now is, good luck as you won't be getting any more help from me.

Comment: The reason I did not up vote is because what you have essentially posted is just code pasted together that would not compile given the API information I have provided you. While I appreciate the effort, what you have provide is not close to solving the problem I mentioned.

Comment: @chadb, that is reasonable, but is because I do not read minds.

Comment: Expecting an answer that compiles while not providing the API you use is kind of optimistic though.

Comment: @chadb: not sure how my my last message got mangled, but here it is again.  Not upvoting my answer is reasonable since I didn't actually compile, but because I (or most likely anyone here) is able to read minds, you will not get any type of response that would ever compile.

Comment: @rectummelancolique, Adrian: Actually, I did provide API information about functionality but he chose not to follow it.

Comment: @chadb: No, you don't specify an API, you state that it is common knowledge (more or less).  I don't believe that this is a good fit for SO as it is too vague or your question is not actually what you are asking.

Comment: You had mentioned "Assuming that objectrigidbody is yet another matrix", when I had clearly stated that Rotate does not return anything. This, along with other examples went to show that you did not read the information provided and were too fixated on stating that you did not feel the question met your standards of a question, it does actually fit the standards for a stackoverflow question.

Comment: @chadb, no I read the info.  I had made the assumption (an invalid one to be sure) only because you didn't specify any API for your *inferred* matrix class.